# iTunes movie store only shows 100?

Tags: itunes-store

It iTunes Store I can search by name, release date or best sellers.  No matter which method I chose I can only see the first 100 titles. For example, if I sort by name I get titles starting with a number and then the letter

Comment: If you want to elaborate more on the actual problem you are trying to solve here or perhaps explain what device and OS is searching the store, we can be more specific in helping you out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is intentional on Apple's part. The reasons for this are:

- reduce server load with smaller queries
- reduce time to download results to the end user
- prevent scraping the web site for store data (which is against the T&C)
- simpler code on the user end not having to present hundreds of results on one page